# Capture changes in a dynamically updated table

Tags: java, selenium, web-scraping

I have a website which updates a table whenever any stock transaction is made. The content is displayed in web table and each transaction is a new row in the table. Its sorted on timestamp of transaction.
I want to capture any new change the made to the table programmatically. Anyone have an idea on how I can achieve that

Comment: Scrape the website every N minutes and detect the new transactions.

Comment: @sekhu, pls., give the link to the website with the table.

Comment: What tool can I use to scrape the website? The website shows content only for registered/paid user

Comment: Type "java web scraping" into your favorite search engine.

Answer (score 0):

The main steps might be:

1. Scrape the table every N minutes/hours (as *Gilbert* mentioned).
2. Store the latest timestamp (in your DB) so that you parse only records that *younger than the timestamp* of the previous scrape action.
3. You need to take care of pagination. Unlikely all the [new] data are at a first page.

Comment: What tool can I use to scrape the website?

Comment: @sekhucool, do you mean to use a software or service besides a scripting language?